# What does it mean as the sample mean is further from the population mean?

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm currently studying the topics about the statistical significance. For which I got confuse about the alpha level and random sampling error. But I got more confuse about this line that I read:

*The further the sample mean is from the population mean, the less likely it is to occur by chance, or random sampling error.*

Can someone help me to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

If your population has mean $a$, and you sample correctly and repeatedly from said population then the sample means will have a normal distribution around the population mean $a$. Some variance is always expected and is likely, for ex. sometimes you will get a sample mean of $a-0.5$, sometimes you will get a sample mean of $a+0.9$ (completely made-up numbers). Either way they will be "close enough" to the population mean $a$ that it is still likely that your sample comes from a population with mean $a$, the difference of $-0.5$ or $0.9$ is merely due to "chance" in the sampling procedure. If, however, a sample mean would have a value of say $a+3$ (made-up), then you would say that getting such a sample mean, if indeed the population mean is equal to $a$, is very unlikely, hence it is likely that this particular sample comes from a population with a mean different from $a$.